# Alexa session remains open with no prompt to the user. Why does certification feedback fail?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Amazon is telling "submission has failed the certification process".

If I repromt the same text in speak and repromt

```
.speak(speechOutput)
.reprompt(speechOutput)
```

```
After the skill completes a task, the session remains open with no prompt to the user. The skill must close the session after fulfilling requests if it does not prompt the user for any input.

Steps To Reproduce:
User: "Alexa, öffne blick analytics"
Skill: "Blick Analytics gestartet. Du bist nicht authentifiziert. Nenne die Parole!"
User: "XXX"
Skill: "Parole richtig, du bist authentifiziert."
User: "wieviele besucher hatten wir gestern"
Skill: "Gestern hatten wir X Millionen Nutzer. Juhuu, das ist X Prozent über dem Tagesziel." and the session remains open.

Please ensure that the session only remains open when the user is prompted for input.
```

If I delete the repromt function it fails with

```
The skill prompts users for an input then immediately closes the session. Make sure the session remains open anytime users are prompted for inputs.

Steps To Reproduce:
User: "Alexa, starte blick analytics"
Skill: "Blick Analytics gestartet. Los gehts."
User: "zahlen gestern"
Skill: "Wir hatten X Millionen Seitenaufrufe. Das ist X Prozent vom Tagesziel entfernt mit dem wir Nummer 1 werden. Sag WEITER für mehr."
And the session gets closed.
```

What's the proper output for keeping the session open?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer has nothing to do with the code, but with the text you return.

You have to communicate to the user at any time that you keep the session open.

So have both

```
.speak(speechOutputForSpeak)
.reprompt(speechOutputForRepromt)
```

either as the same text or even better I think with different text.

The output of .speak() has to end with something like. "Do you have more questions?" to tell the user that the sessions remains open

I used repromot() with just "More questions?"

Example what Alexa will do:

```
User: "How many users yesterday?"
Skill: "We had X Million users. Do you have more questions?" 
User: "How many pageviews yesterday?"
Skill: "We had X Million pageviews. Do you have more questions" 
Repromt Skill: "More questions?" 
User: "Female share yesterday?"
Skill: "... Do you have more questions?" 
Repromt Skill: "More questions?" 
User: No Interaction after Repromt
Closing the skill
```